# Whitespace, Special characters and escape sequences

Tags: c, character

Can anyone explain what are these in detail and the differences between them. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? In strings/literals? In source code?

Comment: There are entire Wikipedia articles about each character set mentioned. Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Comment: I mean in source code.

Answer (score 1):

escape sequence is a sequence of characters that represents something else. e.g. ("\n" = new line, "\?" = question mark, etc.). for more detailed list check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

white space is any character or sequence of characters that represent horizontal or vertical space. for more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

special character is any non-alpha and non-digit char

note: these are not disjoint groups: "\t" is an escape seq. and a special char and a white space

Answer (score 0):

My definitions:

1. White-space: non-visible characters (spaces, tabs, newlines)
2. Special characters: non-alphanumeric characters (! @ # $ % ^)
3. Escape sequences: characters that have some special meaning or effect when interpreted